# How to add QnA Maker to the CoreBot Sample

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am working on a bot based on the C# Core-Bot sample.

How can I add a QnA Maker instance? It should be called if the intent is "none".

Thanks

EDIT:

```
 switch (topIntent)
        {
            case "None":
                //connect with QnA Maker
                return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QnADialog), topIntent, cancellationToken);
```

How does the QnADialog should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a specific issue within core-bot? If you could share some code and add some more direction on what you're trying to do, we might be able to give a more specific answer.

I am using a similar function and based mine off of the [Dispatch Bot Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch/bots/dispatchBot.js) (nodejs but there should be C# version as well). Essentially, you just have it call your QnA Maker function if the intent is None. Or really, you can just create a default case, which will grab None as well as any other intent you haven't explicitly defined.

The example linked above calls a local function, but you can just as easily call a QnA Maker dialog or use any other method of invoking QnA Maker for that default case. Basically any samples for calling QnA Maker can be inserted there. I actually swapped my function call out a while ago to call a helper for the experimental QnA Maker with Prompts sample, which is called as a dialog, so I can confirm both methods work.

**Edit:** In nodejs, I'm calling the dialog inside a switch statement. Because of the way I set this up, I need to do some additional processing to get the actual activity to send. As I noted, this was based on the experimental QnA Maker with prompts sample.

```js
default:
    var processResult = await this.qnaDialog.processAsync(userDialog.qnaState, context.activity);
    userDialog.qnaState = processResult[0];
    await this.userDialogStateAccessor.set(context,userDialog);
    var output = processResult[1];
    await dc.context.sendActivity(output);      
    break;
```

Comment: I saw the sample you mentioned. But i started with the CoreBot Sample. The Code/Classes are completely different. How did a QnA Dialog looks like (return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QnADialog), CatchedIntent, cancellationToken);)?

Comment: I see you're using C#, so I can't say exactly. But I'll add my calling of QnA Dialog to my answer in nodejs and hopefully that will help.

Comment: Could you maybe add the Code from your qnaDialog as well? Review my code above. I dont know how the QnA Dialog should look like. I just want to connect my QnA Maker (Chitchat) for Intent "None".

Comment: If you want ONLY chit-chat and you don't have to worry about prompts, you can do this without calling a dialog. I think I will create a separate answer for this for clarity, but leave this as there is some additional information that may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

With the updated scope of just creating a QnA Maker connector for chit-chat database, I've created a separate answer for clarity. For additional information on options to call QnA Maker from your bot, check the other answer.

First, you need to create the connector/recognizer. You can call the API directly but this is much easier. Then just call the recognizer in your switch statement. Personally I've always set a default message here rather than on the QnA Maker service, but that's up to you.

```js
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');

constructor() {
    this.qnaRecognizer = new QnAMaker({
        knowledgeBaseId: process.env.kbid,
        endpointKey: process.env.endpointKey,
        host: process.env.hostname
    });
}

// <<LUIS call and other code here>>

switch (topIntent) {
    case "None":
        //connect with QnA Maker
        // Set value for number of answers and confidence threshold, e.g. 1, 0.5
        const qnaResult = await this.qnaRecognizer.generateAnswer(context.activity.text, QNA_TOP_N, QNA_CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD);
        if (!qnaResult || qnaResult.length === 0 || !qnaResult[0].answer) {
            await turnContext.sendActivity(`I'm sorry, I don't know how to help with that.`);
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity(qnaResult[0].answer);
        }
    break;
}
```

If you want I can share a dialog example too, but mine is much more complex (the dialog has two nested calls, one for a business KB and the second for chit-chat, and those calls are handled in a separate helper function which calls API directly instead of using the connector/recognizer). I think this should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, i will outsource my QnA Maker, to use it in the MainDialog. Its not that easy like it sounds.